# Is it possible to overload SpringBoot's ConstraintValidator isValid method?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot

Essentially, my service takes the role of streamlining the delivery of Email Notifications for standardization/control. I've therefore exposed a POST endpoint which takes in an email Bean as the response body which holds information such as receiver, sender, cc, etc and I would like to verify the fields of the incoming bean (i.e. email address format).

Currently, I have written a custom validator for validating a list of email addresses (@EmailAddresses). Is there a way to reuse the same validator to validate the email address for the "from" property which isn't a list as opposed to introducing another validator?

My Bean:

```
public class Email {

    @JsonProperty("from")
    private String from;

    @EmailAddresses
    @JsonProperty("to")
    private List<String> to;

    @EmailAddresses
    @JsonProperty("cc")
    private List<String> cc;

   // some other fields
}
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deliverEmailNotification(@Valid @RequestBody Email email) {
        // something
    }
}
```

My Custom Validation Annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmailAddressesValidator.class)
public @interface EmailAddresses {

    String message() default "Must be a valid email";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validation Implementation:

```
public class EmailAddressesValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<EmailAddresses, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(EmailAddresses emailAddresses) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final List<String> emails, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So essentially I'm wondering whether is it possible to do something like this:

```
public class EmailAddressesValidator implements 
ConstraintValidator<EmailAddresses, List<String>>, ConstraintValidator<EmailAddresses, String>  {

    @Override
    public void initialize(EmailAddresses emailAddresses) {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final List<String> emails, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        // do something
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final String email, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Didn't manage to implement two instances of the ConstraintValidator due to Duplicate class error. However, I was able to achieve the equivalent of overloading by having the validation interface be validated by two implementation classes.

Based on the field type annotated with the validation annotation (@EmailAddress in this case), the respective validation implementation will kick in.

```
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { EmailAddressValidator.class, EmailAddressesValidator.class })
public @interface EmailAddress {

    String message() default "Must be a valid email";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Validation implementation for List of Strings

```
public class EmailAddressesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailAddress, List<String>> {

    ...
}
```

Validation implementation for String

```
public class EmailAddressValidator implements ConstraintValidator<EmailAddress, String> {

    ...
}
```